# iText 7 signature field alignment

Tags: vb.net, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

I'm trying to make a signature field in iText, **but the name is not getting aligned with the underline.**

Left underline needs to be centralized with left name, and same in other side... And they **have** to be **side by side**

How can I do that?

Code:

```
Paragrafo.Add(New iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph().AddTabStops(New iText.Layout.Element.TabStop(400, TabAlignment.RIGHT)).Add("_____________________________              ").Add(New iText.Layout.Element.Tab()).Add("_____________________________"))
Paragrafo.Add(New iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph().AddTabStops(New iText.Layout.Element.TabStop(400, TabAlignment.RIGHT)).Add("MICHEL SANTOS DO NASCIMENTO").Add(New iText.Layout.Element.Tab()).Add("CLEDOMIR JOSE BERLATTO"))
document.Add(Paragrafo.SetFontSize(12).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT))
```

Result of code:

[image]

Comment: For the record, I think that the English word you're looking for is "signature". That's probably not too important for the issue at hand though, because it doesn't really matter what the lines are for.

Comment: I used google translator but seens it failed... I made the changes, thanks a lot... @jmcilhinney

Answer (score 0):

There are nicer ways to add the signature lines into your PDF - you can add tab stops and tab leaders instead of adding dashes. Then you can use central alignment for tab stops to make sure your text is aligned as you want.

Example code (it's in Java, but you can easily convert it yo VB.NET similarly to how I converted your VB.NET code into Java):

```
// Tab stops represent left and right coordinates for two lines
java.util.List<TabStop> tabStopsLines = Arrays.<TabStop>asList(new TabStop(50),
        new TabStop(250, TabAlignment.LEFT, new SolidLine()),
        new TabStop(300), new TabStop(500, TabAlignment.LEFT, new SolidLine()));
document.add(new Paragraph().addTabStops(tabStopsLines).add(new Tab()).add(new Tab()).add(new Tab()).add(new Tab()));

// Tab stops represent centers of the lines
java.util.List<TabStop> tabStopsText = Arrays.<TabStop>asList(new TabStop(150, TabAlignment.CENTER),
        new TabStop(400, TabAlignment.CENTER));
document.add(new Paragraph().addTabStops(tabStopsText).add(new Tab()).add("MICHEL SANTOS DO NASCIMENTO").add(new Tab()).add("CLEDOMIR JOSE BERLATTO"));
```

Visual result:

[image: result]